# What is the runtime complexity (big O) of the following pseudocode?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I recently had a very, very intense debate about the runtime complexity of a super simple algorithm with a colleague of mine.  In the end we both agreed to disagree but as I've been thinking about this, it's challenged my basic understanding of computer science fundamentals and so I therefore must get additional insight on the matter.

Given the following python, what is the Big-O runtime complexity:

```
for c in "How are you today?":
    print c
```

Now, I immediately called out that this is simply on the order of O(n) aka linear.  Meaning it's dependent on the length of the string so therefore this loop will grow linearly as the length of the string grows.

My colleague then said, "No, it's constant because we know that for the set of all strings we are dealing with (in our case), the max string is always 255 characters long (in our case), therefore it must be constant."  He followed on by saying "because we have a max upper-bound on character length of the string this results in O(255) which reduces to O(1)."

Anyways, we went back and fourth and after 45 minutes of both of us drawing sketches we both dead-locked on the issue.

My question is in what world or what math system is the loop above a constant time loop?  If we knew our upper-bound was say 1,000,000 characters and the set of all strings could be anywhere from 0 to 1,000,000 this loop will obviously exhibit linear running times depending on the size of the string.

I additionally asked him if he also thinks the following code is O(1) if the upper-bound size of n is known.  Meaning we are certain this code will only ever operate on a max upper-bound of say 255 characters:

```
s = "How are you today?"
for c in s:
    for d in s:
        print c+d
```

He said this is also constant time....even after I explained this is an O(n^2) algorithm and demonstrated that the following code would produce a quadratic curve.

So, am I missing some theoretical concept where any of the above is true depending on how the theory goes?  **Just to be clear his understanding is that I am correct if n is not known.  If the upper-bound of n is always known he is asserting that the two algorithms on this post are both of constant runtime complexity.**

Just looking to maintain my sanity, but perhaps if I'm wrong there's certainly some additional learning I can benefit from.  My good, good colleague was very convincing. Also, if anybody has additional links or material on the subject specific to this question please add to the comments.

Comment: Clearly these two examples have running times as a function of the size of the input; the first is O(n) the second O(n2) - your colleague is trying to count angels on a pinhead!

Comment: With your description of how he thinks that everything boils down to O(1), it sounds like he doesn't understand what big O notation actually means. If you tried to explain it to him for 45 minutes and he flat-out refused to admit that his understanding of it is anything less than perfect, it sounds like you have [a different problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) on your hands.

Comment: Picking a value for n doesn't instantly turn any algorithm into O(1).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It is not a value for N that was chosen; it is a value of C that was chosen - that is *independent* of N. The value was given in a precondition and thus I was free to choose it. The only way to discuss Big-O proper is to consider N -> Infinity. While the wall-clock time definitely follows the expected patterns, it is outside the technical definition.

Comment: Of course this doesn't make for a very good representation of the expected performance..

Comment: That doesn't make it a less complex algorithm, though. It's the same O(n) algorithm - the maximum input just lets us determine if this O(n) algorithm is suitable for whatever application we want to use it in.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Big-O has a definition of f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. In this case the valid (although pedantic) argument is made that n < 256. The correct 'answer', would be to bop someone on the head and tell them to stop being difficult - and to let the *finite* the tape machine (computers) represent an ideal *infinite* tape system, removing the restriction such that the execution time of the function can be usefully analyzed. (It might be good to argue this through 'no maximum integer'..)

Comment: @user2864740 - No, constraining N does not allow you to say that an O(N^2) algorithm runs in O(1) time. Your value of C of (256*256) is high enough for any input less than 255 characters, but as you said yourself, Big-O notation is for considering performance as N approaches infinity. The argument that N < 256 is NOT valid, as then you're not discussing Big-O notation at all.

Comment: @rmunn I absolutely agree with that conclusion, but applied to *everything* - especially as the *finite N* assumption/constraint was also accepted by the poster. Although playing the devil's advocate, I am not choosing a side - well, other than to be the advocate, and to oppose the unfair and non-technical "he flat-out refused to admit that his understanding [is wrong]" comment. Having something explained does not mean that it is correct; and as I've argued, it was not technically correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking a purely mathematical question rather than one specific to programming (that it happens to be asked in the context of Python is irrelevant, given that the topic (big O notation) and the accepted answer are purely mathematical). A better site might be the Computer Science site (currently in beta, however), Math Overflow, or Programmers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Applying Big-O notation to a single scenario in which all the inputs are known is ludicrous.  There *is* no Big-O for a single case.

The whole point is to get a worst-case estimate for arbitrarily large, ***unknown* values of *n***.  If you already know the exact answer, why on Earth would you waste time trying to estimate it?

**Mathy / Computer-Sciencey Edit:**

Big-O notation is defined as *n* grows arbitrarily large:  f(*n*) is O(g(*n*)) if g(*n*) ≥ *c* * f(*n*), for any constant *c*, **for all *n* greater than some *nMin***.  Meaning, your "opponent" can set *c* to "eleventy-quadjillion" and it doesn't matter, because, for all points "to the right" of some point *nMin*, the graph of "eleventy-quadjillion times f(*n*)" will lag below g(*n*)... forever.

> Example:  2<sup>*n*</sup> is *less than* or equal to *n*<sup>2</sup>... for a short segment of the x-axis that includes *n* = 2, 3, and 4 (at *n* = 3, 2<sup>*n*</sup> is 8, while *n*<sup>2</sup> is 9).  This doesn't change the fact that their Big-O relationship is the opposite: O(2<sup>*n*</sup>) is much greater than O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), because Big-O says *nothing* about *n* values less than *nMin*.  If you set *nMin* to 4 (thus ignoring the graph to the left of 4), you'll see that the *n*<sup>2</sup> line *never* exceeds the 2<sup>*n*</sup> line.
>
> If your "opponent" multiplies *n*<sup>2</sup> by some larger constant *c* to raise "his" *n*<sup>2</sup> line above your 2<sup>*n*</sup> line, you haven't lost yet... you just slide *nMin* to the right a bit.  Big-O says that no matter how big he makes *c*, you can *always* find a point after which his equation loses and yours wins, forever.

**But**, if you constrain *n* on the right, you've violated the prerequisites for any kind of Big-O analysis.  In your argument with your co-worker, one of you invented an *nMax*, and then the other set *nMin* somewhere to the right of it --- surprise, the results are nonsensical.

For instance, the first algorithm you showed does indeed do about *n* work for inputs of length *n*... in the general case.  If I were building my own algorithm that called it *n* times, I would have to consider mine a quadratic O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm... again, in the general case.

But if I could *prove* that I would never call your algorithm with an input greater than say 10 (meaning I had more information, and could thus estimate my algorithm more precisely), using Big-O to estimate your algorithm's performance would be throwing away what I'd learned about its *actual* behavior in the case I care about.  I should instead replace your algorithm with a suitably large constant --- changing *my* algorithm from *c* * *n*<sup>2</sup> to *c* * 10 * *n*... which is just *cBigger* * *n*.  I could honestly claim my algorithm is linear, because *in this case*, your algorithm's graph will never rise above that constant value.  This would change *nothing* about the Big-O performance of your algorithm, because Big-O is not defined for constrained cases like this.

To wrap up:  *In general*, that first algorithm you showed was linear by Big-O standards.  In a *constrained case*, where the maximum input is known, it is a mistake to speak of it in Big-O terms at all.  In a constrained case, it *could* legitimately be replaced by some constant value when discussing the Big-O behavior of *some other algorithm*, but that says absolutely nothing about the Big-O behavior of the first algorithm.

In conclusion:  O([Ackermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values)(*n*)) works fine when *nMax* is small enough.  Very, very small enough...

Comment: I agree with this point and brought it up to him, Big-O gives us a framework to compare algorithms depending on the size of their inputs.

Comment: Ludicrous is right. For a particular finite value of N a finite C can also be chosen (in which point it runs in finite wall-clock time). The point of Big-O is to describe N -> Infinity.

Comment: @user2864740:  Good point, which neatly sums up the gigantic edit I was typing when you made it.

Comment: While I think all the responses I got from this post have something good to learn from this particular answer in my opinion I think captures the essence of how I wish I could have explained the details to my friend.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

### In your case...

I am tempted to say that your friend is softly wrong. And that's because of the *considerably big additional constant of 256 in O(1) run time*. Your friend said that the execution was O(256). And because we ignore the constants in Big-O, we simply call O(256 * 1) as O(1). It is up to you to decide whether this constant is negligible for you or not.

---

I have two strong reasons to say that you are right:

Firstly, for various values of *n*, your answer of O(n) (in first code) gives a better approximation of the running-time. For example:

1. **For a string of length 4:** you say run-time is proportional to 4, while you friend says it is proportional to 1 (or 256).
2. **For string of length 255:** you say the running time is proportional to 255 while your friend again says that it is constant time.

Clearly, **your answer is more accurate in every case**, even though his answer is not outright wrong.

Secondly, if you go by your friend's method, then in one sense you can cheat and say that since no string can go beyond your RAM + disk size, therefore all processing is in O(1). And that's when the fallacy of your friend's reasoning becomes visible. *Yes he is right that running time (assuming 1TB hard disk and 8 GB RAM) is O((1TB + 8GB) *1) = O(1), but you simply cannot ignore the size of your constant in this scenario.*

---

**The Big-O complexity does not tell the actual time of execution, but just the simplistic rate of growth of the running time as the value of n increases.**

Comment: I don't think you can say that he is right (i.e. his collegue is wrong) because his estimation is better. Landau symbols are theoretical computer science (math originally...), they work with infinite storage. And because big O is an upper bound, O(n) works as well when O(1) works. 
I'd consider this O(1) because 255 is rather small. There are many more cases where 255 is considered small rather than large.

Comment: @Sbls: That is why I have said in my answer that it is up to them to decide whether the constant is negligible or not. First para, last line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're both right.

The runtime of the first algorithm is linear in the size of its input. However, if its input is fixed, then its runtime is also fixed.

Big O is all about measuring the behavior of an algorithm *as its input changes*. If the input never changes, then Big O is meaningless.

Also: O(n) means that the **upper bound** of complexity is N. If you want to represent a **tight bound** then the more precise notation is Θ(n) (theta notation).

Comment: So like I said, the input is not fixed.  It is potentially 0-255 so does this still hold true?

Comment: But the upper bound is fixed. For example, adding two numbers is technically O(n) in the number of bits in the two numbers. But in practice we typically think of it as O(1) since the numeric types we use have a fixed upper bound on number of bits (32 or 64). Does that make sense?

Comment: So I agree that if the input was fixed...the runtime is also fixed.  But when comparing both algorithms on the exact same input you would never say they are both O(1).  You **cannot** ignore the exponent.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree. You are correct. Your colleague is making a technically correct point, but in a context that makes it meaningless. Either way, with the constraints on the problem you have described, big O is not a useful framework for comparing possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You're both right in a way, but you're more right than your colleague. (**EDIT:** Nope. On further thought, you're right and your colleage is wrong. See my comment below.) The question really isn't whether N is *known*, but whether N can *change*. Is `s` the input to your algorithm? Then it's O(N) or O(N^2): you know the value of N for this particular input, but a different input would have a different value, so knowing N for this input isn't relevant.

Here's the difference in your two approaches. You're treating this code as if it looked like this:

```
def f(s):
    for c in s:
        print c
f("How are you today?")
```

But your colleague is treating it like this:

```
def f(some_other_input):
    for c in "How are you today?":
        print c
f("A different string")
```

In the latter case, that for loop should be considered O(1), because *it's not going to change* with different inputs. In the former case, the algorithm is O(N).

Comment: Actually, on re-reading your post I have to retract my statement that you're both right. Your colleague is **wrong**. Since you're dealing with different strings, `s` is the input to the algorithm. The fact that you know an upper bound on how large N can get is irrelevant to O(N) analysis; what's important is that as N grows, O(N^2) grows much faster than O(N). That N has an upper bound of 255 does not change that fact, it just means that you might be able to get away with an O(N^2) algorithm in this particular case.

Comment: The OP clearly states there is a maximum size of N. As such there is a C that can be chosen to make it O(1), as Big-O (being academically inspired) only discusses the upper-bound, but such is cut short at a finite limit; so while the wall-clock time definitely is affected by the input size (and even according to an expected curve) a maxim (constant) value can be determined.

Comment: That doesn't make it an O(1) algorithm. Imagine someone with an O(n^2) algorithm for entering a username, and you tell them "what if someone has a username with a million characters?" and they respond "well, we limit it to 20 characters." Do you tell them "well, an O(n^2) algorithm is okay then," or "well, then it's actually an O(1) algorithm"?